# Passing value of a controller to another controller through its directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, parameter-passing, directive

I have a template that uses another directive inside it similar to this:

```
<my-directive current-obj="myOriginalController.currentObject" data="4"></my-directive>
```

Here's how my directive is defined:

```
function myDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    bindToController: {
      currentObj: '=?',
      data: '=?'
    },
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: 'myController'
  };
}
```

And this is how my controller is defined:

```
export default class MyController {

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.currentObj);
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

The first console statement returns null, while the second one returns 4 as expected.

I can see the value of myOriginalController.currentObject, which is an object, using this if I place it somewhere in my first template:

```
{{ myOriginalController.currentObject }}
```

However, when I try to pass it to my other directive, the value doesn't show up in the controller of other directive. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`bindToController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) mentions that bindings can be accessed inside a controller method by the name of `$onInit` (one of the life cycle hooks provided by Angular). This method is called after all controllers on an element have been constructed and bindings have all initialised.

In light of that, simply replace your `constructor` method with `$onInit` and you should have `currentObj` initialised and ready for you.

[<kbd>Plunker Demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Hd6AAXHivYL9dRdw75s?p=preview)